# Close window by keyword

Tags: c, winapi

I want to close all the windows that has any keywords assigned. Below is the C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define WINVER 0x0600
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>

BOOL CALLBACK WindowFoundCB(HWND hwnd, char* param) {
    char *key = (char*) param;
    char strIte[256]; // This way, you have allocated 256 bytes for the Window name.
    GetWindowText(hwnd, strIte, 256);
    if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd)){
        char *p = strstr(strIte,key);
        if (p!= NULL){
            SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
            printf("==== close a window by key [%s]: <%s>\n",key,strIte);
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        printf("...keep closing window 1Hz for: %s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    if (argc > 1){
        while (1){
            for (i = 1; i < argc; i++){
                char* aStr = argv[i];
                EnumWindows(WindowFoundCB,&aStr);
             }
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I run it, it only prints the message:

> ...keep closing window 1Hz for : myKeyword

Then there is no further reaction at all, even if I have a window named "jjjj myKeyword--".

By the way, is there a way to make case-insensitive compare for searching of keyword here?
Thanks.

Comment: Your `WindowFoundCB` expects a `char*`. You are passing a `char**`.

Comment: Hi, I use EnumWindows(WindowFoundCB,aStr) instead, but this time the programme exit upon start.

Comment: You successfully closed your own window.  Use GetConsoleWindow() to bypass your own.

Comment: My own window title does not have the matched keyword, so the strstr should return NULL?

Comment: Hi, Hans Passant,

It worked! Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

As @GSerg and @Hans Passant pointed out, there are two issues:

1. Pass `aStr` instead of `&aStr` to `EnumWindows`.

`lParam` of [`EnumWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) is an application-defined value to be passed to the callback function. The callback function you defined expect `char*` instead of `char**`.

2. When you call your application from command window your keyword will be included in your console window title like below picture shows. ("project" is the keyword here.) So your application window will also be closed since it contains the keyword. Exclude it using `GetConsoleWindow()`.

[image]

```
ownWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
//...
if ((p != NULL) && (hwnd != ownWnd)) {
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
    printf("==== close a window by key [%s]: <%s>\n", key, strIte);
}
```

> By the way, is there a way to make case-insensitive compare for
>   searching of keyword here?

You can convert both keyword and window title to lowercase and then compare them.

```
char* aStr = argv[i];
//To lowercase
for (int i = 0; aStr[i]; i++) {
    aStr[i] = tolower(aStr[i]);
}
EnumWindows(WindowFoundCB, aStr);

//...

//To lowercase
for (int i = 0; strIte[i]; i++) {
    strIte[i] = tolower(strIte[i]);
}

char *p = strstr(strIte, key);
```